# How do I make a code take multiple inputs and execute the same operation on all of them

Tags: c, loops

[Beginner]

So I want to write a code to check whether a number is Armstrong number or not, How do I make my program take multiple inputs and then perform the same exact function on all of then and then print the result, for e.g. the program below will take only one value and num and then print whether its Armstrong or not, I will have to define 3 inputs as num1, num2, num3 and then write the function for all three separately for it to work, and i don't want that...

What I want is
for e.g. when i run the program it should ask for 3 inputs as:

input 1 [press enter]

input 2 [press enter]

input 3 [press enter]

[and then display the result as]

Armstrong

Armstrong

Not Armstrong

So the program should treat 'input 1 as num'
then 'input 2 as num'
and finally 'input 3 as num'
and then display the result

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int num, originalNum, remainder, result = 0;
    printf("Enter a three-digit integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    originalNum = num;
      while (originalNum != 0) {
       // remainder contains the last digit
        remainder = originalNum % 10;
        
       result += remainder * remainder * remainder;
        
       // removing last digit from the orignal number
       originalNum /= 10;
    }

    if (result == num)
        printf("%d is an Armstrong number.", num);
    else
        printf("%d is not an Armstrong number.", num);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Use an array of three (or more) elements.

Comment: can you write down the code the starting bit at least

Comment: Here you are. enum { N = 3 }; int num[N]; for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) { printf("Enter a three-digit integer: "); scanf("%d", num + i); //... }